# Get group of Numbers that add up to form a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a number n = 8 and k = 4,

I want to arrange n into groups of k that adds up to n

example:
assume n = 7 and k = 3 expected result should be: {1 1,5}, {1,2,4}, {1,3,3}, {2,2,3} which is (4)

n = 4 and k =  2 expected result should be: {2,2}, {1,3} which is (2)

I have tried to get a pair that add up to a number.
I want to know how I can solve it efficiently without solving for k individually.

```
function answerQuery(n, k) {

  const items = [];

  let pairs = 0

  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    items.push(i)
  }

  let a = 0;
  let b = items.length - 1;

  while (a <= b) {
    let tmp = items[a] + items[b];

    if (tmp == n) {
      pairs ++
    }
    a++;
    b--;
  }
  return pairs
}
```

Comment: Where are you using `k` in this function?

Comment: I can use k to check ```if k=2 it should perform the pairing . of two numbers and also do for all occuring k value. I don't want this. I want to cater for all occuring k value instead of doing if condition for all occuring k.